# Names on second marriage certificates in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, marriage

Assuming a woman was married before and assumed her first husband’s name and never changed it back after her divorce, if she marries again, would the marriage certificate show her maiden name or the first husband’s name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate will show the name she goes by at the time with "divorced" recorded as her Condition in section 4 (or "disolved" for civil partnerships).

(I speak from experience but can't find a reputable link at the moment.)

Comment: Hmm... Won't it be whatever name she names herself at the time of the 2nd marriage?

Comment: @Greendrake  No, not in the UK. Her name on the certificate is the name she goes by before the marriage is solemnised. For example, when Miss Smith marries Mr Jones these are the names in part 2 of the certificate regardless of whether she subsequently goes by Mrs Jones.

Comment: So if her name was Mary Smith, she gets married and becomes Mary Jones and then marries Mr. Brown, the second marriage certificate will show that Mary Jones is getting married to Mr. Brown. Can she ask to show that Mary Smith is marrying Mr. Brown?

Comment: @user  Sorry, I've no idea!

Comment: @user She can certainly change her name back to her maiden name, but I assume that would need to be done before the new marriage. And the UK seems to be very flexible about name changes in general (compared to Germany which has absolutely zero flexibility).